# Is it still possible (as of 2020) to access documents stored in SharePoint with Word 2003?

Tags: word

In some cases, I'd like to edit certain Word documents (*.docx) in Word 2003, instead of using Word 2019/365.

I have tried "[Start Online Collaboration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2AWKl.png)" from the "Tools" menu -- but got an "Unknown Network Error" from there.

Is it still possible somehow -- and if yes, how would I go about it?

(I'm not sure whether I have all optional Office 2003 components installed that could be needed)

Answer (score 3):

No.

For an updated list of supported versions of Office, see [Office versions and connectivity to Office 365 services](https://docs.microsoft.com/deployoffice/endofsupport/office-365-services-connectivity).